widgets not filling entire frame using Tkinter
Here is my code -
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Food shopping")
root.geometry('800x500')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
# root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

# Blank space top left
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.configure(bg='red')
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe', padx=5, pady=5)

# Frame containing the 4 buttons
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.configure(bg='blue')
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe", padx=5, pady=5)

# Frame containing the first check boxes
frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
frame3.configure(bg='green')
frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nswe", padx=5, pady=5)

entry_btn = ttk.Button(frame2, text="Add")
entry_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')

entry_btn2 = ttk.Button(frame2, text="Clear")
entry_btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='we')

entry_btn3 = ttk.Button(frame2, text="Continue")
entry_btn3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='we')

entry_btn4 = ttk.Button(frame2, text="Finish")
entry_btn4.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='we')

root.mainloop()

and this is what it produces

The only reason the frames are coloured is so i can clearly see them. Why are the buttons not filling the entire blue frame? and why is the blue frame bigger despite having the same weight as the other frames?

None of the columns in frame2 has non-zero weight, therefore they were no wider than necessary to hold the Buttons they contain.  And weight only affects excess space - notice that the unused part of the blue Frame is exactly as wide as the unused (entire) part of the red/green Frames.  If you want blue to be the same overall width as red/green, you want uniform= (with the same value in each column, it doesn't matter what that value is) in addition to weight=.

By default, grid will only use enough space to fit the natural size of the widgets. If you want a row or column to expand to use extra space you have to explicitly configure it that way.
For example, if you want the two rows in the blue frame to take up the whole area, give them a weight of 1 with rowconfigure
frame2.grid_rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)

Similarly, if you want the three columns to fill the space, use columnconfigure:
frame2.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1)


Seems to have solved the issue. Thank you

@Bryan Oakley. How could you position entry_btn4 in between those three buttons without any space?

@toyotaSupra: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You can add it to any row and in any column you want. Just move the other buttons over one.

Three widgets on top and one widget on bottom. Without spacing between widgets

@toyotaSupra: I don't follow. This already has three buttons on top and one below. If you don't want spacing, just adjust the various options on grid and on the buttons themselves. Maybe you need to ask in a question rather than as a comment.
